# Зачем нужен массив Class[]

Tags: java, android

К примеру я создал массив

```
Class[] cl = new Class[]{main.class, maintwo.class};
```

Но как использовать этот массив, можете привести пример?

Пробовал в методе Intent не получилось.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам функционал можете почитать тут: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html
Как использовать? Завернуть в цикл или поток, проверить наличие входящего объекта на инстанс этого класса, инциализировать их и дальше использовать, etc.

Comment: GenCloud подскажи как инициализировать массив Class[]?
Class[1] = new Class не получается(